# PHP - DOMDocument scrape divs dont remove images

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-match, domdocument

that is my current php code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@class="test"]');
if ($divs->length > 0) {
    foreach ($divs as $key => $div) {
       print_r($div);
    }
}
```

In every div is also an image which I also want to output but DOMDocument is removing it.

The images are implemented like in the html file:

```
<img src="loading.gif" data-src="https://test.com/images/images/120/1313131313232.jpg" alt="test" />
```

I want to ouput the value of data-src additionally to the text in the div.

Thank you,
With best Regards

Comment: You are querying divs with classes equal to `test` and that img tag includes an `alt` equal to `test`. Hence not being included.

Comment: Please  share the `div[@class="test"]` html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every div you could use `$div->getElementsByTagName("img")` to get the image. Then loop the images check if the alt attribute of the img is `test` and get the `data-src` attribute:

```
@$dom->loadHTML($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@class="test"]');
foreach ($divs as $key => $div) {
    echo $div->textContent . "<br>";
    foreach ($div->getElementsByTagName("img") as $img) {
        if ($img->getAttribute('alt') === 'test') {
            echo $img->getAttribute('data-src') . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/B8pic)

Answer (score 0):

> ***I want to output the value of `data-src` additionally to the text in
>   the `div`.***

I'm not aware of any "*text in the div*" in your question.
To get the `value` of `img` attribute `data-src`, you can use `getAttribute('data-src')`, i.e.:

```
$html = <<< L
<img src="loading.gif" data-src="https://test.com/images/images/120/1313131313232.jpg" alt="test" />
<img src="loading.gif" data-src="https://test.com/images/images/120/1313131313233.jpg" alt="test" />
<img src="loading.gif" data-src="https://test.com/images/images/120/1313131313256.jpg" alt="test" />
L;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query('.//img[contains(@alt, "test")]'); # or query('.//img[contains(@src, "loading.gif")]');
foreach ($divs as $img) {
    print($img->getAttribute('data-src')."\n");
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
https://test.com/images/images/120/1313131313232.jpg
https://test.com/images/images/120/1313131313233.jpg
...
```

---

[PHP Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QOo)